# Use specific Java JRE version in Azure Function

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-zulu

I have an Azure function that was previously working on Java JRE version: **zulu8.52.0.23-jre8.0.282-win_x64(X)**, but recently after an Azure update, it went from that version to a new version: **zulu8.54.0.21-jre8.0.292-win_x64(y)**.

I accessed the azure function using kudu and found out that version **X** is still there in the directory, but the path variable is referring to the latest JRE available on the machine i.e version **Y.**.

[image: JRE LIST]

What I need is to go back to the previous JRE version that the function was previously running on.

Comment: Have you checked the [Azure Functions Java developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption#supported-versions) document ?